# IndentationError And Other Errors

Tags: python

```
def URLGen(Model. size):
BaseSize = 500
# BaseSize is for shoe size 6.5
ShoeSize = 6.5
ShoeSize = ShoeSize - 6.5
ShoeSize = ShoeSize x 20
RawSize = ShoeSize + int(RawSize)
URL = https://www.adidas.com/us/ + str(model) + '.html?forceSelSize=' +
str(model) + str(ShoeSizeCode)
return URL
Model = raw_input('Model #')
Size = input('Size: ')

URL = URLGen(Model. size)

print (str(URL))
```

Im quite new to python and am coding an autimated URLGen for adidas.com and am getting multiple errors to do with IndentationError: unexpected indentation, expected in indented block, and expected white space around operator. However i am copying this code from a already made URLGen that works.

https://gyazo.com/b3d8a87fffd21dd26adb8206a17faf2b

Comment: The code you're copying really does have an indentation issue. The contents of a function should be indented by 4 spaces

Comment: there's no way this works

Comment: indents are really important in python, anything inside the function has to be indentated to mark the scope

Answer (score 2):

## Quick formatting

The code should be indent depending on the scope :

```
def URLGen(model, size):
    BaseSize = 500
    # BaseSize is for shoe size 6.5
    ShoeSize = 6.5
    ShoeSize = ShoeSize - 6.5 # this gives 0
    ShoeSize = ShoeSize x 20  # this gives 0
    RawSize = ShoeSize + int(RawSize) # Rawsize is not a number 
    URL = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/' + str(model) + '.html?forceSelSize=' + str(model) + str(ShoeSizeCode) # SHoeSizeCode does not exits
    return URL

Model = raw_input('Model #')
Size = input('Size: ')    
URL = URLGen(Model, size)

print(str(URL))
```

You can find the indentation rules [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).

## Other errors

You have various other errors present:

### Function calls and definition

```
def URLGen(Model. size):
```

and

```
URL = URLGen(Model. size)
```

Python uses a `,` to separate the variables and not a `.` like you used.

### Variables not created or used properly

- `RawSize = ShoeSize + int(RawSize)` Here you use `int(RawSize)` but `Rawsize` contains nothing
- `URL = https://www.adidas.com/us/ + str(model) + '.html?forceSelSize=' + str(model) + str(ShoeSizeCode)` Here you use `model` but you declared `Model`, so `model` doesn't exist and `ShoeSizeCode` just doesn't exist.

## Important note

It is very bad practice to just copy paste code and use it. You don't know how or why it was coded, nor its dependencies, leading to errors you don't understand the origin of.

If you plan on coding in python, I'd suggest first reading up on how to use it properly and then try out for yourself rather than just copy pasting code you think will work.